Set up timezone for timezone for all nodes in databricks without init script
I have used this question to set up pyspark timezone using configuration of the cluster with
spark.sql.session.timeZone Asia/Hongkong

This, unfortunately does not set timezone for all nodes and therefore calling pythons datetime.datetime.now() will not include timezone set with spark session config.
Databricks is phasing out support of init scripts and therefore I cannot use it to set up timezone for all nodes.
How is it possible to do it during spark config?

'rolling out' means?

I got a message from them saying that DBFS init scripts no longer will be supported and gradually will stop working  since march 2024

That is not what 'rolling out' means. That means introducing.

Did you find a solution to this?

Hey, not really
